# ASP.NET: How can I get the domain name without any subdomains?

Tags: .net, dns

I've been searching here on SO but I can't seem to find the answer to this question.  I'm having a heck of a time figuring out if there's a method that will give me just the main domain from the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`?

Examples:

http://www.example.com > `example.com`
http://test.example.com > `example.com`
http://example.com > `example.com`

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit

just to clarify a bit. This is for use on my own domains only and not going to be used on every domain in existence.
There's currently three suffixes that I need to be able to deal with.

- .com
- .ca
- .local

Comment: `www.thingy.co.uk` > `thingy.co.uk`

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean a way to extract the domain name from a URL contained in a string?

Comment: I clarified my question a little.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public static void Main() {
    var uri = new Uri("http://test.example.com");

    var fullDomain = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Host, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped);
    var domainParts = fullDomain
        .Split('.') // ["test", "example", "com"]
        .Reverse()  // ["com", "example", "test"]
        .Take(2)    // ["com", "example"]
        .Reverse(); // ["example", "com"]
    var domain = String.Join(".", domainParts);
}
```

Comment: I like this. And though it won't work for `.co.uk` it should work just fine for my purposes.

Comment: It also won't work for localhost! I'm looking for a way to get the root domain for any request. Might be localhost, might be domain.com might be domain.co.uk

Comment: @StefanBergfeldt, define "won't work". It would output "localhost" for input "http://localhost".

Comment: @SimonSvensson I got an emtpy string back when trying with localhost.

Comment: for ".co.uk" it won't works. For localhost (and others) it seems perfect.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Public_Suffix_List) for a list of suffixes that allow arbitrary registrations.

Find the longest suffix of the full domain name in that list, then return everything after the last `.` before that suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of top level domains, and match every domain with that list, taking only 1 word after the match.

(you might need to add some support for .co.
ect...

Comment: That is a hell of a long list, especially if you take all the ccTLD's into account also. Still, the only reliable way, except perhaps finding a list of the ccTLD's and then applying this except with 2 segments of the domain name.

Comment: The problem is that some countries as more than 1 word in the "top level" domain name, so you need to find a way to track though name, and not treat them as co.uk b/c here co is not the domain name, but co.com will work....

Comment: @Matthew: That's not good enough; different ccTLDs have different policies.  https://wiki.mozilla.org/Public_Suffix_List

Answer (score 0):

Here's the idea that I've come up with.
@SLaks, I'd love to here your thoughts on this.

```
    ''# First we fix the StackOverflow code coloring issue.
    <Extension()>
    Public Function PrimaryDomain(ByVal url As Uri) As String

        If url.Host.Contains("example.com") Then Return "example.com"
        If url.Host.Contains("example.ca") Then Return "example.ca"
        If url.Host.Contains("example.local") Then Return "example.local"
        If url.Host.Contains("localhost") Then Return "localhost"

        Throw New Exception("The url host was not recognized as a known host name for this domain.")
    End Function
```